# Determine if time overlap exists among given date ranges

Tags: algorithm

There are given extremely many data ranges (starting and ending dates). I'm trying to find the most effective way to determine if the given (new) data range makes any overlap to any other. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you need to do anything other than confirm the existence of overlap (e.g. identify the overlapping range(s), count the number, etc...)?

Comment: Is sorting and checking for overlaps not possible?

Comment: @vivek_23 Sure, it's possible but it requires O(N*Log(N)) time and O(N) space. Any better ideas? I mean, its doable but the things is what would be the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a constant-time approach. Maintain timestamps in a tree: Year -> month -> day -> hour -> minute -> second -> however fine grained you want.

To check a new date range:

```
1. Traverse the tree, creating new nodes as needed, to add the start-of-range 
   timestamp.
2. Back up to the highest common node and retraverse the tree from there, again 
   creating new nodes as needed to add the end-of-range timestamp.
3. As you move between the two timestamps, check every node you pass for children 
   that live between the two timestamps. If you find any then there is overlap.
```

By storing a little more info in the tree, you could identify specific overlapping ranges (vs just existence), and produce the number of overlapping ranges.

Simple M/D example:

Range 1: 1/19 - 3/19

Range 2: 2/19 - 4/19

After range one is added the tree has three nodes: year 2019, month 1 and month 3, with edges 2019 -> 1 and 2019 -> 3.

We process range 2 by adding 2019 -> 2, then back up to 2019 and notice that  2019 has the child 3 which lives between 2 and 4. Finally we add the node for month 4.